# Any one know is there any possible to change the alert msg "loqi.me would like to install 'Geoloqi'" while install the .ipa file using OTA method

Tags: ios, ota

Any one know is there any possible to change the alert msg **"loqi.me would like to install 'Geoloqi'"** while install the .ipa file using OTA method.

[Check the Screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwf7k.png)

Answer (score 0):

No. I am sorry, but there isn't any method to change this. This method is there to be recognizable as an important (and maybe dangerous) action. Customization would allow disguise it.